# CrossThread Exception: How do I modify one thread from another in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a multi-threaded form loader, and I'm trying to modify one thread from another:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button4.Enabled = false;
        progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
        progressBar1.Value = 1;

        new Thread(new ThreadStart(CompareVersions)).Start();
    }
```

How can I set into the`CompareVersion` started in a new thread that he has to set in the previous one `progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 1;` to start the Animation of the Marquee?

Steps:

1. start a method on a new thread
2. Update the `MarqueeAnimationSpeed` to 1 from the new thread into thread (1)

Visual Studio warns me that I can't modify an existing thread from a new thread.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Clarify the question, please.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I think Simon had got the crossThreadException when trying to : progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 1

Comment: Are you trying to update the UI from another thread? That won't work, you'll have to marshal access or use the background worker that raises events that are marshalled already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define it into a new method or class, calling it, and before you start the new thread you can simply set that MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 1 ;  last, catch the thread exit and you re-set MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;

Comment: is not wasted, as you can not directly interract with the new thread u create, u set that "Flag" before the thread start and on thread close you reset to 0. a little trick :)